# Docker Compose - one specific container randomly doesn't start properly

Tags: jboss, docker, wildfly, docker-compose

I have a docker environment with 5 containers that are composed via docker compose. Now only on mac machines and only sometimes (seems completely random) 1 of these 5 container doesn't start.

The weird thing about it is, that docker ps says the container is running and I can connect to it. Inside the container is a JBoss server and ps says that there is a process that runs the JBoss. BUT in fact the JBoss is not up and running. There is no logging in the docker compose console and JBoss not accessible.

There is also the problem that if this happens the whole docker-compose process cannot be canceled properly anymore. All containers shutdown and also can be forced to shutdown but the JBoss container. Then the docker-machine hangs up.

I didn't find any hint in the interwebs ... please help !

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't precise enough for anyone to give you anything but debugging suggestions

Comment: debugging suggestions are also good :) ... what info would be helpful ?

Comment: your issue seems to be JBoss related only. I would try to find the JBoss server log which shows the how the initialisation process went

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the process running inside the container is in a weird state. 
Try killing it without providing a grace period, or removing the container.

```
stop : Stop a container by sending SIGTERM and then SIGKILL after a
grace period

  --help=false       Print usage
  -t, --time=10      Seconds to wait for stop before killing it
```

---

```
kill : Kill a running container using SIGKILL or a specified signal

  --help=false           Print usage
  -s, --signal="KILL"    Signal to send to the container
```

---

```
rm : Remove one or more containers

  -f, --force=false      Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
  --help=false           Print usage
  -l, --link=false       Remove the specified link
  -v, --volumes=false    Remove the volumes associated with the container
```

Moreover try checking the logs of the container:

```
docker logs --follow <container_name or container_id>
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating to docker v1.10 the problem didn't occur anymore :)